# convert array containing a single key object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array containing single key objects like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [state] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [state] => 1
        )

)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1

    [1] => 1

)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I'm not quite sure how to put this problem in simple words, so I can't google it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `array_map`:

```
$result = array_map(function($object) {
    return $object->state;
}, $originalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a for loop :

```
for $array in $val
   $val =$val[state]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk) and pass the value in by reference:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v, $i) { 
    $v = $v->state;
});
```

or

```
array_walk($array, create_function('&$v', '$v = $v->state;'));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you got one of the newer PHP versions you can do that with a foreach loop and a reference:

```
foreach ($array as &$value)
{
  $value = $value->state;
}
```